# How can I check my query history when using Robo 3T for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

When I use Robo 3T for MongoDB, can I have my query history scripts stored in Robo 3T, just like pl/sql developer for oracle?  this is a very key function cause often times I need to check my previously query inputs.

Comment: You can see your recent queries in robo3t "Logs". For saving queries,you should use Studio3T or MongoDB Compass.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some simple ways to check **query history** in Robo 3T:

1. Switch to the **View** tab then choose **Logs** option.
2. Click on **Logs button** in the bottom left corner of the screen to show the Logs panel.
3. Shortcuts are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for trigger Logs panel.

[image]

Comment: There's no way to store this between the sessions?

Comment: IF anybody has figured a way to get the query history across sessions, do let us know.